# How to retrieve child elements of certain element from XML using XPATH?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML document:

```
<resultset>
<table>
    <name>RESULTS</name>
    <data>
        <row>
            <field name="TradeId" type="xs:integer">1185652601</field>
            <field name="TradeVersion" type="xs:integer">1</field>
            <field name="TradeDate" type="xs:date">20190807000000</field>
            <field name="tradeLastUpdatedTimestamp" type="xs:dateTime">2019-08-07 18:16:20.475078+01:00</field>
        </row>
    </data>
</table>
<table>
    <name>CustomCalcPeriod</name>
    <data>
        <row>
            <field name="CouponSchPayDateAdj" type="xs:date">20160920000000</field>
            <field name="CouponSchCouponAmount" type="xs:double"/>
            <field name="CouponSchRate" type="xs:double">5</field>
        </row>
    </data>
</table>
<table>
    <name>CustomNotionalStep</name>
    <data>
        <row>
            <field name="AnnuitySchNotional" type="xs:double">10000000</field>
            <field name="NotionalSchStartDateAdj" type="xs:date">20160620000000</field>
            <field name="NotionalSchStartDateUnadjusted" type="xs:date">20160620000000</field>
        </row>
    </data>
</table>
```

Using XPATH I would like to retrieve list of "row" elements separately for each table: RESULTS, CustomCalcPeriod, CustomNotionalStep. So far I only managed to extract entire nodes using the following expressions:

```
"//name[text()='RESULTS']"
```

Can I extend this expression so that it returns a NodeList of "row" elements belonging only to the parent table, without the rest?

Comment: There is no `CustomCalcPeriod` in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
//table[name/text() = 'RESULTS']/data/row
```

```
//row[../../name/text() = 'RESULTS']
```

Both of these XPath expression should give the following output (Which I think is what you want)

```
Element='<row>
        <field name="TradeId" type="xs:integer">1185652601</field>
        <field name="TradeVersion" type="xs:integer">1</field>
        <field name="TradeDate" type="xs:date">20190807000000</field>
        <field name="tradeLastUpdatedTimestamp" type="xs:dateTime">2019-08-07 18:16:20.475078+01:00</field>
    </row>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the final output is supposed to be, but this expression:

```
//table//row
```

should select 3 `<row>` groups for each `<table>`.